# Grafana Elastic-Datasource not finding time field

Tags: elasticsearch, datasource, grafana

Given following mapping:

```
{
  "iot_data" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "device_data" : {
        "properties" : {
          "device_id" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton",
            "cql_partition_key" : true,
            "cql_primary_key_order" : 1
          },
          "nano_since_epoch" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton",
            "cql_primary_key_order" : 2
          },
          "sensor_id" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton",
            "cql_primary_key_order" : 3
          },
          "source" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton"
          },
          "time" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton"
          },
          "unit" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton"
          }
          "value" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton"
          },
          "week_first_day" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "cql_collection" : "singleton",
            "cql_partition_key" : true,
            "cql_primary_key_order" : 0
          }
        }
      }        
    }
  }
}
```

I´m trying to add a datasource to grafana, but it keeps on telling me that no date field has been found. What am I doing wrong? Is grafana unable to handle the "long" field as time field? 
We have data that is inside of the same ms since epoch, that is why nano_seconds is used.

[image]

I am aware, that grafana needs an Date field as described here:
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4321#issuecomment-282467390

Is it somehow possible to use a non-date field for x-axis with the elastic datasource?

Comment: Hi @Alex do you have any solution on this, In my case-my timestamp field is custom formatted - "time_stamp": "2019-04-24|15:10:50" so Grafana is not able to find this column (No date field name found)

Comment: Nope, i didnt investigate further